# Toggle visibility on selected (current) layer in photoshop

Tags: photoshop

How do I toggle visibility on selected (current) layer in photoshop?
Can I do it without scripting? If no, where do I find such script?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a shortcut by default for this, but you can make one in the Keyboard Shortcuts configuration (Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts).

Under Layers > Show Layers

Answer (score 1):

In the layers view, click on the "eye" to toggle the layer on and off.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In code just use:

```
 var currentLayer = activeDocument.activeLayer;
 // toggle visibility of active layer
 currentLayer.visible = !currentLayer.visible
```

Answer (score 0):

In current version of Photoshop (2015) use Ctrl + ,

Answer (score -3):

Record a new action—option/alt click on the eyeball in the layers panel—assign a function key to activate the action.